# Repeated Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose we have to select $2$ chocolates from $3$ brands. The chocolates can be from same brands. So why isn't the number of ways of selecting $2$ from them be $\binom62$ because we can take max $2$ chocolates from a brand. So having $6$ chocolates ($2$ from each brand) lets us have every possibility.
Where am I wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: Any two chocolates from the same brand are identical but in your way of counting you are treating them as different. When you say you are choosing from $6$ chocolates you are thinking $\{a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2, c_1, c_2\}$, whereas it should be thought of as a multiset $\{a,a,..b,b,...c,c...\}$.

Comment: @AnuragA So sir to treat them identically, we should divide them by 2!. But then also the answer wont come,

Comment: Learn mathjax from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible cases.

case 1:you select both chocolates from same brand.

```
   number of ways in which you can do this=(3,1)
```

case 2:you select 2 chocolates from different brands.

```
   number of ways in which you can do this=(3,2)
```

Hence,total number of ways=(3,2)+(3,1)=6

*remember that chocolates of the same brand are identical.Hence (6,2) cannot be the answer*

Comment: Sir so if they are identical, can we divide (6,2) by 2! and get the answer?

Comment: no. When you take C(6,2),you are assuming that all chocolates are different objects.let the chocolates be a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2. in C(6,2) the selections will contain {a1a2,a1b1,a1b2,a2b1,a2b2,b1b2,.......} .but actually the second third fourth and fifth elements are the same.hence we need to subtract 3 cases from every possible combination of three brands. thus answer will be C(6,2)-3*C(3,2)=6